# While running cypress tags, All the feature files were running and checking weather the required tag is present in the feature file or not

Tags: javascript, tags, cucumber, cypress

`'sudo xvfb-run -a npm run test-tags:${environment} --env tags="@REG2"'`

We are running above command for segregating test cases using tags, but still all the test scenarios were running

Package.json:

`{ "name": "cypresspackage", "version": "1.0.0", "main": "index.js", "scripts": { "test-tags:qa3": "cypress run --config-file config/qa3.config.js --browser chrome --headed --env hars_folders=./cypress/hars", }, "devDependencies": { "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^18.0.1", "@bahmutov/cypress-extends": "^1.1.0", "@cypress/browserify-preprocessor": "^3.0.2", "@neuralegion/cypress-har-generator": "^5.16.4", "@shelex/cypress-allure-plugin": "^2.23.0", "allure-commandline": "^2.17.2", "cypress": "^12.17.0", "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^4.3.1", "cypress-file-upload": "^5.0.8", "cypress-xpath": "^1.6.2", "mocha-allure-reporter": "^1.4.0" }, "description": "", "dependencies": { "node": "^18.16.0", "npm" : "7.0.0", "prettier": "^2.5.1" }, "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": { "filterSpecs": true, "omitFiltered": true } }`

Features files:

In the feature files we have configured everything correctly, because in the cypress version 8 they were worked but we have upgraded to version 12, it was not working now

I want to make tags should work with their dedicated cases

We have tried using "grep" also but not worked

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.